# Python 2/3: Why is type(Foo.__init__) different?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, types

Consider the class:

```
Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

Executing `type(Foo.__init__)` on Python 2:

```
Python 2.7.5 (default, Mar  9 2014, 22:15:05)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> class Foo(object):
...     def __init__(self):
...             pass
...
>>> type(Foo.__init__)
<type 'instancemethod'>
```

Executing `type(Foo.__init__)` on Python 3:

```
Python 3.4.1 (default, May 19 2014, 13:10:29)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.1 (clang-503.0.40)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> class Foo(object):
...     def __init__(self):
...             pass
...
>>> type(Foo.__init__)
<class 'function'>
```

Why is the return of `type(Foo.__init__)` different on Python 2 and 3?

Comment: The entire object model was redesigned. Notably, the concept of unbound methods was removed. What are you doing where this matters?

Comment: Is it not  `builtins.function`?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham You are right. Silly copy and paste mistake. Now fixed.

Comment: @Wooble My goal is to check whether the constructor is defined or not. I ran into this problem while converting my current code from Python 2 to Python 3.

Comment: @Trein: Why do you need to know its type to know whether it's defined? (More to the point: If I used my a decorator that turned my `__init__` into a different kind of callable or descriptor, why should that not still count as being defined?)

Comment: @Wooble: You should write that as an answer (with links to the docs); it seems like a good question, and that's definitely a good answer.

Comment: @abarnert I'm working on a dependency injection framework. That's why.

Comment: @Trein: And? Why does your dependency injection framework care what type `Foo.__init__` is? If it exists, and it's callable, what else do you need to know?

Comment: @abarnert Your insightful thoughts are welcome: https://github.com/google/pinject

Comment: @Trein: Without even the slightest clue of what part of that mass of code is relevant, I'm not going to read through all of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're asking *what* changed, the short version is in [What's New in 3.0](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#operators-and-special-methods):

> The concept of “unbound methods” has been removed from the language. When referencing a method as a class attribute, you now get a plain function object.

In more detail:

A function object is a [descriptor](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html) whose `__get__` returns a method. In Python 2.x, it looks like this (in pure Python pseudocode, and slightly simplified):

```
class FunctionType(object):
    # other stuff
    def __get__(self, instance, cls):
        return MethodType(func=self, instance=instance, cls=cls)

class MethodType(object):
    def __init__(self, func, instance, cls):
        self.__func__, self.__instance__, self.__class__ = func, instance, cls
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.__self__ is not None:
            return self.__func__(self.__self__, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return self.__func__(*args, **kwargs)
```

So, when you write `Foo.__init__`, you get back the unbound method `MethodType(__init__, None, Foo)`.

In 3.x, it instead looks like this:

```
class FunctionType(object):
    # other stuff
    def __get__(self, instance, cls):
        if instance is not None:
            return MethodType(func=self, instance=instance)
        else:
            return self

class MethodType(object):
    def __init__(self, func, instance):
        self.__func__, self.__instance__, self.__class__ = func, instance, type(instance)
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.__func__(self.__self__, *args, **kwargs)
```

For the full details, see The standard hierarchy in the reference docs for [3.x](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy) vs. [2.x](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy), under "Callable Types".

---

If you're asking *why* it was changed… well, as far as I remember, there wasn't much discussion on this—no PEP, no long discussion on python-dev or -ideas, etc.—and it was only given that one line in the docs.

But the reasoning seems pretty obvious. Unbound methods aren't particularly useful; they're just extra scaffolding that provides the exact same behavior as the function they're wrapping.* They were only there in 2.2-2.7 to better model the behavior of classic classes** and/or because it seemed easier to implement that way and/or because early in the design it wasn't clear that you could implement things like `@classmethod` without it, and by the time Guido got far enough to realize that there was no problem there, it was easier to leave the design as he'd originally written it.

---

<sub>* The CPython implementation of bound methods adds an `isinstance` check to verify that the first argument is a `self.__class__`, but that isn't clearly documented, nobody's written code that relies on it, and it isn't as helpful for debugging as you'd expect.</sub>

<sub>** If you want to know why classic classes worked the way they did, you have to dig through Guido's [Python History](http://python-history.blogspot.com) blog—all of which is worth a read if you've got the time.</sub>